# How to Update Frames for all Size Classes in a Storyboard in Xcode 6.1?

Tags: xcode6, scene, size-classes

When working with Storyboard files in Interface Builder on Xcode 6.1, Apple recommends designing for the Any/Any size class. When finished, different size classes sometimes report warnings:

**Misplaced View - Frame for "Some Button" will be different at run time.**

You can fix by doing the following:

1. Change to one of the nine Size Classes.
2. Select a Scene.
3. `Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> (All Views) Update Frames`
4. Repeat steps #2 and #3 until all Scene's in a Size Class have their frames updated.
5. Go to step #1 and repeat until all Size Classes have been updated.

This is pretty cumbersome if you have, say, 20 different Scene's in a Storyboard (20 x 9 size classes = 180 manual frame updates).

Is there a way to tell Xcode 6.1 to "Update Frames" for every Scene, in every Size Class, in one command?